# wpf dictionary binding where key=variable

Tags: wpf, binding, dictionary

I have a test dictionary

```
MyDict = new Dictionary<string, Uri>
{
    {"First", new Uri("alma.jpg", UriKind.Relative)},
    {"Second", new Uri("korte.jpg", UriKind.Relative)}
};
```

and a simple XAML

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyDict[First]}"
           FontSize="13" Width="200" Height="30" />
```

That shows perfectly the First key element Value

What I want is
I have a string variable: DictKey
Lets DictKey="First"

How to rewrite the XAML to use this variable

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyDict[???DictKey????]}"
           FontSize="13" Width="200" Height="30" />
```

thx.

Comment: Please see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186) about how to format code blocks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I assume you have some property `DictKey` which holds the key of the item. 
You can use `MultiBinding` and set the first binding to your dictionary property and second binding to the property with the key of the item:

```
<TextBlock FontSize="13" Width="200" Height="30">
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding>
            <MultiBinding.Converter>
                <local:DictionaryItemConverter/>
            </MultiBinding.Converter>

            <Binding Path="MyDict"/>
            <Binding Path="DictKey"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

The converter uses both values to read the item from dictionary:

```
public class DictionaryItemConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values != null && values.Length >= 2)
        {
            var myDict = values[0] as IDictionary;
            var myKey = values[1] as string;
            if (myDict != null && myKey != null)
            {
                //the automatic conversion from Uri to string doesn't work
                //return myDict[myKey];
                return myDict[myKey].ToString();
            }
        }
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```