# How do I bind Dictionary Value based on Key to a TextBlock in Code-Behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, dictionary, code-behind

I am using the MVVM model with a dynamic field generator, where the field is pulled from the database, done this way because different types of forms require different fields (TextBox/TextBlock, ComboBox, etc.). The problem is I'm trying to retrieve a value from a dictionary, to display in a TextBlock for the form, but I'm not sure how to bind the retrieved Key so I can display the value.

Currently, I am doing the following:

```
 TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
 textBlock.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, createFieldBinding(myPropertyName);
```

With the following binding method:

```
 private Binding createFieldBinding(string fieldName) {
      Binding binding = new Binding(fieldName);
      binding.Source = this.DataContext;
      binding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.LostFocus;
      return binding;
 }
```

Where I pass something through like `Score`, which maps to a `Score` property in the ViewModel, but how would I bind to a Dictionary Key to retrieve its Value?

I want to be able to bind to something like `myDictionaryProperty[myDictionaryKey]`, if that is possible.

Example:
The below generates the `PlayerScore` for Player with ID of 1.
Where `PlayerScore` is a `Dictionary<int, int>` and `PlayerID` is an `int`.

```
 <TextBlock Name="textBlockA" Text="{Binding PlayerScore[1]} />
```

Comment: You would have to create a [MultiBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx), as explained in the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13799705/1136211) asked today.

Comment: I don't know MVVM.  I just use Source to the Dictionary and  Path = Value

Comment: @Clemens Awesome, thanks for that! Took me a while to tinker for what I wanted, but that solution works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13800383/1466627) provided by @Clemens, I was able to build my own DictionaryItemConverter, based on the data types for my Dictionary, and create a multi-binding method that would bind the `Key` and the `Dictionary` together.

Converter:

```
 public class DictionaryItemConverter : IMultiValueConverter {
      public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
           if(values != null && values.Length >= 2) {
                var myDict = values[0] as IDictionary;
                if(values[1] is string) {
                     var myKey = values[1] as string;
                     if(myDict != null && myKey != null) {
                          //the automatic conversion from Uri to string doesn't work
                          //return myDict[myKey];
                          return myDict[myKey].ToString();
                     }
                }
                else {
                     long? myKey = values[1] as long?;
                     if(myDict != null && myKey != null) {
                          //the automatic conversion from Uri to string doesn't work
                          //return myDict[myKey];
                          return myDict[myKey].ToString();
                     }
                }
           }

           return Binding.DoNothing;
      }

      public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
           throw new NotSupportedException();
      }
 }
```

Multi-Bind Method:

```
 private MultiBinding createFieldMultiBinding(string fieldName) {
      // Create the multi-binding
      MultiBinding mbBinding = new MultiBinding();
      // Create the dictionary binding
      Binding bDictionary = new Binding(fieldName + "List");
      bDictionary.Source = this.DataContext;
      // Create the key binding
      Binding bKey = new Binding(fieldName);
      bKey.Source = this.DataContext;
      // Set the multi-binding converter
      mbBinding.Converter = new DictionaryItemConverter();
      // Add the bindings to the multi-binding
      mbBinding.Bindings.Add(bDictionary);
      mbBinding.Bindings.Add(bKey);

      return mbBinding;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Binding to indexed properties is possible and uses the same notation as C#, just like you wrote:

```
<TextBlock Name="textBlockA" Text="{Binding PlayerScore[1]}" />
```

The string you pass to "createFieldBinding" is the property path. If you set the source as the dictionary, you just need to pass the indexer part, like "[[1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path.aspx)]", as if you had done like this in xaml:

```
<TextBlock Name="textBlockA" Text="{Binding [1]}" />
```

[See this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path.aspx)

Comment: What about if `1` is a property?

Comment: If you set the source correctly and want to bind to a property named "1", just use "{Binding 1}". If "1" is a property of the object returned by the index, then you just append it to the path "{Binding [MyIndex].1}" (assuming the binding source is a dictionary or a object which implements indexer). Note that in C# identifiers cannot start with a numeric character http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670.aspx