# XAML bind dictionary item with variable key

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'd like to bind dictionary's item using variable as a key, for example:

`PanelNames.cs`

```
public static class PanelNames
{
    public static string Panel1 = "Panel1";

    public static string Panel2 = "Panel2";
}
```

`MainWindowVM.cs`

```
IDictionary<string, object> Panels { get; }
```

`MainWindow.xaml`

```
<TextBlock Content="{Binding Panels[Panel1]}" /> <-- this works fine, because Panel1 is simply string

<TextBlock Content="{Binding Panels[PanelNames.Panel1]}" /> <-- this doesn't work, because there is no key with such name, but I want to keep names outside XAML file and use PanelNames static class.
```

Is this possible to access Dictionary element using variable as a key in XAML? I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799705/wpf-dictionary-binding-where-key-variable) post, but it doesn't meet my requirements.

Comment: You want to show only one item or multiple items?,

Comment: Simply I want to avoid using hard coded strings. Instead of typing hardcoded key, I'd like to use constat value. Both approaches fetch me SINGLE value from dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of hardcoding a string in the XAML, you should bind this to another property:

**View**

```
<TextBlock Content="{Binding PanelValue}" />
```

**ViewModel**

```
IDictionary<string, object> Panels { get; }

private string _panelValue;
public string PanelValue
{
    get { return Panels[_panelValue]; }
    set
    {
        // Make sure Panels has this key,
        _panelValue = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PanelValue));
    }
}
```

So in your code, you can set `PanelValue` to the key whose value you want to display in the TextBlock.

Comment: I'd like to avoid using logic in ViewModel to get value from dictionary. I was thinking about using some converter first, but earlier I'd like to research whether my idea is possible.

Comment: This one is flexible. If you don't want then I guess converter is the solution,